# Showing $\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v$ is an optimal solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

$$\max \quad c \cdot x  \\ \mathrm{s.t.} \ Ax \leq b\\ x\geq 0 \\$$

There are two optimal solutions to the LP $u$ and $v$. How do I show that for $\lambda \in [0,1]$,  $\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v$ is also an optimal solution

- First, I have to show that $\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v$ has the same value of the objective function as $u$.
- Then show $\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v$ is a feasible solution.

For 1) how would I approach this problem and then show that $\lambda u + (1-\lambda)v$ is a feasible solution? Would appreciate any tips, help and explanation.

Comment: the feasible set is convex, because the intersection of two convex regions is a convex region, and that a constraint $\sum_i a_{ij} x_i < b_j$ defines a convex feasible region for $x$ (convex region meaning exactly what you wrote : that any point lying on the segment between two points in the region is still in the region)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes. But how would I show it mathematically?

Comment: I'm sure you can  prove the convex set intersection theorem yourself

Comment: For example, you know $u\geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$.  Can you prove that $\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v \geq 0$? You know $Au \leq b$ and $Av \leq b$, can you prove the same for $\lambda u + (1-\lambda) v$?

Comment: This may be helpful.  You need to do one or two of these steps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation

Comment: @Michael Thanks a bunch!